# 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found on GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h - Flutter iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a Flutter project where the Android build is working totally fine, but the iOS build was broken by 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found on GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h file.

I have tried all possible solutions for upgrading my Flutter SDK, all dependencies, removing pod files and installing them again, even tried deleting the whole iOS project and recreating the iOS project and setup again.

Still, I am facing this issue.

Please consider the below screenshots for the flutter doctor and issues.

[image: flutter doctor]

[image: issue on android studio]

[image: issue on xcode]

Please let me know the possible solution and what am I doing wrong here.

Looking for positive solutions, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a dependency. A package or plugin is not completely installed or there is an error in installation. Just try to `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` few times and this will install all dependencies correctly and this error will be gone. Thank you